# jquery find with child selector included

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i am sure this is widely known, but i just stumbled upon this. using jquery find() combined with a child selector.

so with structure like this.

```
<div id="first">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div><div></div></div>
</div>
```

then using jquery find to grab the divs within first, excluding the inner div.

```
$('#first').find('>div');
```

the selector spec says this though, suggesting that > followed by something would grab all children.

E > F   Matches any F element that is a child of an element E.

so my question is what is jQuery actually saying in that statement. it seems to say grab the immediate children, excluding its children. is that an accurate statement?

Comment: Any reason you're not just using `$('#first > div')`?

Comment: maybe helpful: http://jsfiddle.net/2nP5m/

Comment: this isn't my code, i am going through one of the filament group exercises and that's how they have it written.

Comment: Note the warning about how that syntax will be deprecated in a future jQuery release here: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Answer (score 1):

With this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jTpee/3/

It seems that its taking only the first level of children

But as they say, you can also use this : http://jsfiddle.net/jTpee/2/

Comment: that example made it click for me. i wasn't visualizing it as #first > div for some reason. the .find() was throwing me off.

Comment: Maybe you could write it as accepted answer if it helps you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just try this. It will return only first level of childs.

```
$('#first > div');
```